# Select rows that come after a condition, under a condition in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2], 
             'time': [1,2,3,4,1,2,5,6],
             'is': [0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0]})

id  time    is
0   1   1   0
1   1   2   1
2   1   3   0
3   1   4   0
4   2   1   0
5   2   2   1
6   2   5   0
7   2   6   0
```

which is `sorted` by `id` and `time`

I want for each `id`, to select only the rows that satisfy at least one of the two conditions:

- `is==1`
- the rows after the rows where `is==1` and `time` between these 2 rows, does not have gaps.

The resulting dataframe should look like this:

```
pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,1,2], 
             'time': [2,3,2],
             'is': [1,0,1]})
```

How could I do that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`groupby.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.Shift.html):

```
# form groups
g = df.groupby('id')

# select rows with is==1 and the next ones (per group)
m1 = df['is'].eq(1) | g['is'].shift().eq(1)
# select rows with successive time
m2 = g['time'].diff().eq(1)

out = df[m1&m2]
```

Output:

```
   id  time  is
1   1     2   1
2   1     3   0
5   2     2   1
```

Answer (score 2):

**Code**

```
cond1 = df['is'].eq(1)
cond2 = df.groupby('id')['time'].diff().le(1)
df[cond1 | (cond2 & cond1.groupby(df['id']).shift())]
```

output:

```
id  time    is
1   1   2   1
2   1   3   0
5   2   2   1
```